# How can I avoid switch statement in this case

Tags: java, oop

I want to avoid using a `switch` statement but I don't know how.
This is my problem:

```
public class Person{
    String status;

    public void doSomething(){
        switch (status) {
        case "hungry":
                eatSomething();
                status = "full";
            break;
        case "full":
                doNothing();
                status = "hungry";
        default:
            break;
        }
    }}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
    public abstract class Person{
        public abstract void doSomething();
}

public class HungryPerson extends Person{
        @Override
        public void doSomethink() {
            eatSomething();
        }
}


public class FullPerson extends Person{
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
            doNothing();
    }   
}
```

The problem is: if the `Person` ate something then he has to be `FullPerson`, but if I had a reference with `HungryPerson` how can I change it to `FullPerson`?

```
int main(){
    Person person = new HungryPerson();
    person.doSomething();
    //I want to person contain a FullPerson reference.
}
```

Comment: If this question is about Java, tag it as such.

Comment: Keep status as private member variable in Person class and in the constructor method of both child class ( HungryPerson and FullPerson),  set the status to "full" or "hungry" depends on the class. Also from the doSomething method of both the child class, change the status according to the need

Comment: you can't just change the type of an object. You may be able to use reflection and replace a method to invoke based on status, but I doubt it would be justifiable from a design point of view.

Comment: I would stray away from using a statement in the class name. For example, being hungry or full is describing the state of that Person. Because of that, it's not so easily changed. If you wanted to have a `HungryPerson` be able to become a `FullPerson`, you would probably have to have a `public HungryPerson(FullPerson person)` and `public FullPerson(HungryPerson person)`. It doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, your first implementation is better from an Object Oriented point of view.  The state of the object can change but the object itself is still the same object.  You remain the same person even when you are hungry or after you eat.  You might want to use an `Enum` instead of a String for the status.

Comment: I just read about Clean Code and they say avoid the switch statement but then in this case the switch statement is the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

use an if/else.

```
if(status == "hungry")
     doSomething();

doSomethingElse();
```

Comment: If else is same like switch.

Comment: Yes, because the state of the object is contained within it, ideally. Don't worry about mechanics of the tests -- just trust your object state is correct. This is why if if we have many states we typically store then in an enumeration, and use a switch statement. If you don't need that many states, then use a different statement.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the switch statement, you can use if-else.
you can use **if(status.equals("hungry"))** to check if the status of the person is hungry or not and then call the respective methods as you want.